# AFNetworking 2 - get error json body

Tags: objective-c, json, error-handling, response, afnetworking-2

I'm using latest **AFNetworking** for my app which speaks with REST API server.

When I get some `500` error from it with JSON body something like

`{ "message": "my error message" }`,

I cannot retrieve this message from `NSError` which lib responds to me:

```
[api setupUser:data success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   // some success handle
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   // cannot get json response of error :(
}];
```

How do you workaround it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was simple - `operation.responseObject` in failure callback contains json data as well. Sweet ^.^